# exiting a while loop with a negative integer

Tags: c, numbers, while-loop

I want to exit a `while()` when the user enters a negative number of any size.  What kind of condition would I need at the start of the loop to get the loop to exit when the user enters a negative number?

Answer (score 2):

Well, what is a negative number? It's a number (call it `x`) that is less than zero, or symbolically, `x < 0`. If `x` is less than zero, then this is true. If not, then it is false.

You can loop endlessly and break when this condition is met:

```
while (1) {
  if (x < 0) {
    break;
  }

  ...
}
```

But I prefer to just use the opposite of that condition in the `while` loop itself:

```
 while (x >= 0) {
   ...
```

While the condition is true, then the loop continues. When it is false (and your original condition is true, as these two are opposite), the loop breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `if` condition to know the number is less than **0** or not. And if yes, just use `break` statement inside it, which will bring you out of the loop. [Learn more about break statement from MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37zc9d2w%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: @GregS : Correct. But let's not spoon feed OP. Let him think of it after reading from the link or from some other source about `break` statement.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i = -1;
do
{
    i = magic_user_input();
    //simple enough? get a decent programming book to get the hang of loops
}
while(i > -1)
```

**edit: sorry, my mistake: 'i' wasn't declared properly :) now it should be fine to use**

Answer (score 0):

Do not define your variable as unsigned variable. As suggested in other answers use if statement and break with if statement.

example:

```
int main(void)
{
 int i;
 while(1){
 /*here write an statement to get and store value in i*/ 
  if(i<0)
  {
    break;
  }
 /*other statements*/
  return(0);
  }
 }
```