# How to continue scanf if newline is entered?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [exiting a while loop with a negative integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761525/exiting-a-while-loop-with-a-negative-integer)

I want the user to enter few different numbers numbers, and after that to test each number separately.

Also I need to terminate the program **ONLY** when the number `0` entered.

This is the beginning of my code:

```
int userInput;
printf("please enter some numbers: \n");
while ((scanf("%d", &userInput)) == 1)
{
    ...
}
```

How can I keep getting input from the user until `0` is entered?

Comment: Doesn't that loop work already?  What's the problem, exactly?  Are you just looking for something like `if (!userInput) break;`?

Comment: it works, but if i enter 0 it keeps going..@CarlNorum

Comment: not exactly the same as: [exiting a while loop with a negative integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761525/exiting-a-while-loop-with-a-negative-integer) but the concept is. `scanf()` only tells you the # of matches that were entered, 0 is valid for an `int` so clearly you need another type of check to make sure the value entered is not 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
while ((scanf("%d", &userInput) == 1) && (userInput != 0))
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: thanks allot, appreciate it :) @JohnBode

Answer (score 4):

```
while (scanf("%d", &userInput))
{
    if(userInput == 0)
        break;
    /* do sth */
}
```